# How do I tell JsonConvert.SerializeObject to treat a string object as a JSON

Tags: c#, json

How do I tell `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to treat the `UserPreferences` as a JSON-object (it is stored in a db as a string).

```
  public int UserId { get; private set; }

  [[JsonProperty something]]
  public string UserPreferences { get; private set; }

  public CFUser(Int32 userId, string userPreferences) {
      UserId = userId;
      UserPreferences = userPreferences;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option to address your issue is to use a custom `JsonConverter` for the `UserPreferences` property. For that, you'll need to decorate the property with the following attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(UserPreferencesConverter))]
public string UserPreferences { get; private set; }
```

Here is a complete sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfUser = new CFUser(1, @"{""test"":""ok""}");
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cfUser);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject(json, typeof(CFUser));
    }

}

class UserPreferencesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // you may use the following line instead
        //return jObject.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "");

        return jObject.ToString()
            .Where(c => !"\r\n".Contains(c))
            .Aggregate<char, string>("", (s, c) => s + c);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }
}

public class CFUser
{
    public int UserId { get; private set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(UserPreferencesConverter))]
    public string UserPreferences { get; private set; }

    public CFUser(Int32 userId, string userPreferences)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        UserPreferences = userPreferences;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks so much. So UserPreferencesConverter can be used for  anything that contains json strings content inside?

Comment: You are welcome! Basically, yes, it will work for properties of type `string`. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Cool, so can you explain a bit further how this works, in particular the Contains(c) and  "", (s, c) => s + c

Comment: `jObject.ToString()` adds spaces and line breaks to the string. I used `Linq` to remove those unwanted characters from it. I realize now based on your clarifications request that it's not such a good idea, as it could actually modify the values of the variables. I updated the answer by removing the ` (space)` from the characters removed from the string.