# Using JSON.net to Serialize a datatable, how do I stop it from escaping a JSON string in one of the columns

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am serializing a datatable like this in VB.net using JSON.NET, and it's working fine:

```
ResultJSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyDataTable)
```

The problem is that I added another column, (named JSON_Column), to the data table which has JSON strings as values, and now when I serialize the datatable, the SerializeObject method escapes my quotes in the JSON strings in that column with backslashes, so I end up with JSON that looks like this:

```
"ColumnA": "Value1",
"JSON_Column": "{\"SomePropertyName\":\"SomeValue\"}"
```

How can I tell the JSONConvert.SerializeObject method that the string values in the JSON_Column of my datatable should NOT be escaped because they are JSON themselves?

In other words, I want this as the result:

```
"ColumnA": "Value1",
"JSON_Column": {"SomePropertyName": "SomeValue"}
```

It's somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109363/how-do-i-tell-jsonconvert-serializeobject-to-treat-a-string-object-as-a-json), but I am serializing from a datatable, not a custom object, so I can't use that method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `JSON_Column` contains a string, not an object which is why it is escaped, the string contains double-quotes.  You need to serialize it as an object, not a string.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that is the problem - my whole question asks: how do I do that when the JSON is in a datatable?   Is there a way to let the JSON.NET serializer know that column should be treated as an object and not a string?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to write a custom converter to convert that `DataTable` to a JSON string.  You can only tell `JsonConvert` how to convert types so you'll need to provide a converter for `DataTable`.

A `DataTable` is serialized as an array of objects with a property corresponding to each of the values in a row.  You'll want to deserialize the `JSON_Column` column first so it is treated as an object and not a string.  Once you created this new representation of your DataTable, you can let the serializer take care of the rest.

Here's how you could write such a converter:

```
Class MyDataTableConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(type As Type) As Boolean
        Return type = GetType(DataTable)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        Dim dt = TryCast(value, DataTable)
        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim rowSerializer = New MyRowSerializer
            Dim obj = New JArray(
                From row In dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)
                Select rowSerializer.Serialize(dt, row.ItemArray)
            )
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        If existingValue Is Nothing Then
            Dim dt = CreateTable
            Dim rowSerializer = New MyRowSerializer
            Dim arr = serializer.Deserialize(Of JArray)(reader)
            For Each obj In arr.Cast(Of JObject)
                dt.Rows.Add(rowSerializer.Deserialize(dt, obj))
            Next
            Return dt
        End If
        Return existingValue
    End Function

    Private Function CreateTable() As DataTable
        Dim dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("ColumnA", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("JSON_Column", GetType(String))
        Return dt
    End Function

    Class MyRowSerializer

        Public Function Serialize(table As DataTable, values As Object()) As JObject
            return New JObject(
                From x in table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).Zip(values, Function(col, value) New With { col.ColumnName, .ColumnValue = value })
                Let value = SerializeColumn(x.ColumnName, x.ColumnValue)
                Select New JProperty(x.ColumnName, value)
            )
        End Function

        Private Function SerializeColumn(name As String, value As Object) As Object
            Select Case name
                Case "JSON_Column"
                    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(DirectCast(value, String))
                Case Else
                    Return value
            End Select
        End Function

        Public Function Deserialize(table As DataTable, obj As JObject) As Object()
            Dim values = From col In table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)
                         Let columnName = col.ColumnName
                         Let value = obj(columnName)
                         Select DeserializeColumn(columnName, value)
            return values.ToArray
        End Function

        Private Function DeserializeColumn(name As String, value As Object) As Object
            Select Case name
                Case "JSON_Column"
                    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)
                Case Else
                    Return value
            End Select
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

Then serialize your table passing in the converter as an argument.

```
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable, New MyDataTableConverter)
```

Comment: Jeff- thanks for the answer, I seems like it is what I need.  I'm a VB guy, so I'll do the translation and let you know if I have any questions.  Thanks again for your detailed answer!

Comment: Ah sorry, I fully intended to write a VB version but forgot. But hopefully the translation is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: I rewrote it as VB code. My VB is a bit rusty but I believe it is equivalent.

Comment: if i have 2 datatables and i need to convert them in one json string but i need each datatable in json array what shall i do?

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury: If I understand what you're trying to do, you can simply place your datatables into a list (or other collection) and deserialize that list. Make sure to include the converter as an argument.

Comment: okey you are right but how can i add a root tag for every json array in my string?

Comment: in other words i need to add the name of every table at the begining

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury: In that case, you probably don't want an array, but a mapping (an object).  Just place your datatables into a dictionary or maybe even a `DataSet` and serialize. You can give key the tables as you want with a dictionary. A dataset will use the names of the tables as keys.